# How to fetch data from multiple tables in spring boot using mapping in Spring Boot's JPA repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have created four entity classes as:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DashboardRegionCountry")
public class DashboardRegionCountry implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "dashboardId")
    private long dashboardId;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Country.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="countryId")
    private Country country;
    
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Region.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="regionId")
    private Region region;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name="dashboardId")
    private Dashboard dashboard;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Dashboard")
public class Dashboard implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "dashboardId")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long dashboardId;

    @Column(name = "dashboardName")
    private long dashboardName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy= dashboard)
    private List<DashboardRegionCountry> dashboardRegionCountry;
    
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Country")
public class Country implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "countryId")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long countryId;

    @Column(name = "shortName")
    private String shortName;
    
    @Column(name = "longName")
    private String longName;
 
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Region")
public class Region implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "regionId")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long regionId;

    @Column(name = "shortName")
    private String shortName;
    
    @Column(name = "longName")
    private String longName;
}
```

And  the table schemas for the respective entities are as follows:

DashboardRegionCountry:

```
+----------------+---------------+
| Field          | Type          |
+----------------+---------------+
| id(PK)         | Number(11)    |
| dashboardId(FK)| Number(11)   |
| countryId      | Number(11)    |
| regionId       | Number(11)   |
+-------------+------------------+

Dashboard:

+----------------+---------------+
| Field          | Type          |
+----------------+---------------+
| dashboardId(PK)| Number(11)    |
| dashboardName  | varchar(11)   |
+-------------+------------------+

Country:
+-------------+---------------+
| Field       | Type          |
+-------------+---------------+
| countryId(PK)| Number(11)   |
| shortName   | Varchar2(10)  |
| longName    | Varchar2(10)  |
+-------------+---------------+

Region:
+-------------+---------------+
| Field       | Type          |
+-------------+---------------+
| regionId(PK)| Number(11)    |
| shortName   | Varchar2(10   |
| longName    | Varchar2(10)  |
+-------------+---------------+
```

Basically, when user enters the dashboardId then we want to fetch, dashboardDetails along with the Region and respective countries presnt in that region. As stated above, I only have region and country Ids in my table and their names are present in other tables.
I want to display my sample output something like:

```
{
 "dashboardId":20,
  "DashboardRegionCountry": [{
    "Region":"ASIA",
    "dashboardId":["India","China"]
  },
  {
    "Region":"NAM",
    "dashboardId":["USA","Canada"]
  }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to write JPA repository but was wondering is it possible to write something like:

```
@Repository
public interface DashboardRegionCountryRepository extends JpaRepository<DashboardRegionCountry, Long>{

    List<Map<Long,Country>> findRegionBy_RegionId(Long dashboardId);
}
```

I am trying to fetch all the data in one query, any suggestion will be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Just get the corresponding `DashboardRegionCountry` using `getById` (check the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#getById-ID-)) and it will contain both associated `Country` and `Region`. If you then don't want to expose all `Country` and `Region` information in your entities I suggest you map them to a DTO that would be the model that you want to use while returning something on your controllers.

Comment: Hello Sir,
I have updated the question, If I do `findByDashboardRegionCountry_dashBoardId`, it is also fetching the dashboard details which I do not need. Also, it is firing multiple queries, is there any way to do it using single query and fetch only regions and countries?

Comment: For that, you would need to write your own custom query with `@Query` --> https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query.

Answer (score 0):

findByRegion_regionId  try this this will work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).